# Python GTK3+ Using Button to Load Images

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3

I'm creating an app that can use a button to load and display an image. I don't understand how this would work with Python Gtk3+.

I want to load the next image into the GUI location where the first image is... a simple replacement.

```
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file(self.image)
grid.attach(image, 0, 2, 1, 1) #grid location

button = Gtk.Button("Load next image")
button.connect("clicked", self.load_image)
grid.attach(button, 2, 1, 1, 1) #grid location

button1 = Gtk.Button("Load next image")
button1.connect("clicked", self.load_new_image)
grid.attach(button1, 2, 2, 1, 1) #grid location

def load_image(self, widget):
    self.image = 'image_path'

def load_new_image:
    self.image = 'image_path'
```

I thought of Event Boxes, or something similar, but I'm kind of at a loss. The image section is only run once on instantiation, so I don't understand how it should get updated with events. I want the image to change if the `self.image` path name changes in another class method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but should not it be that simple?

I will explain the answer as @DanD. pointed out.

You just need to set the image path (self.image.set_from_file(img)) on the load_image method (connected with the button clicked signal) with the desired image.

Current Gtk.Image will display automatically the new loaded image.

```
import gi
import os
import sys

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class GridWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Grid Example")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        self.image = Gtk.Image()

        grid.add(self.button)
        grid.add(self.image)

        self.button.connect("clicked", self.load_image)

        self.count = 0
        for root, _, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
            self.images = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]

    def load_image(self, event):
        img = self.images[self.count]
        print(img)
        self.image.set_from_file(img)

        self.count = self.count + 1

win = GridWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I think this is it. But I would suggest starting the answer with:  You have to call `image.set_from_file(self.image)` after assigning to `self.image` to load the image.

Comment: @DanD. You are completely right, sorry. Just edited the answer now.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it never occurred to me to call the `set_from_file` again, I thought it was connected as a subscription event to the class variable. This makes way more sense now!